# rails/thin server not responding on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I use thin 1.3.1, rails 3.1.0 on windows. 
thin works well until at some points it is not responding to requests although the process is still active. 
I also tried "gem install eventmachine --pre" but it is still the same situation. 
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem with thin 1.3.1 and eventmachine 0.12.10

Problem triggered by concurrent request, eventmachine will lock up.

Latest trunk of eventmachine seems fixed this issue.

However, thin is not working with latest eventmachine (request OK, just do not response).

Hopeful when eventmachine 1.0 is released, thin will be alse keeped up.

If you in hurry, why not use them in linux platform?